# Why does my fixed div container go behind this relative div container?

Tags: html, css, css-position

This is my HTML with the important elements being `section#landing`, `profile-container`, and `socials-container`

This is my CSS where `profile-container` `position` is set to `relative` and `socials-container` `position` to `fixed`

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cormorant&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cinzel&family=Cormorant&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cinzel&family=Cormorant&family=Montserrat&display=swap');
:root {
  --primary-font: 'Cinzel', serif;
  --secondary-font: 'Cormorant', serif;
  --tertiary-font: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  --primary-image: url('./images/masteroogway.jpg');
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  background-image: var(--primary-image);
  font-family: var(--primary-font);
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}


/* navbar */

nav {
  /* background-color: black;
    opacity: .75; */
  border: solid 2px;
  border-color: blueviolet;
}

nav>ul {
  border: solid 2px brown;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

nav>ul>div.logo-container {
  border: solid 2px goldenrod;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

nav>ul>li {
  border: solid 2px greenyellow;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

nav>ul>li>a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav>ul>li>a:hover {
  color: grey;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px white;
}

nav>ul>div.contact-container {
  border: solid 2px goldenrod;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}


/* landing */

section#landing {
  border: 2px solid rgb(58, 209, 255);
}

.profile-container {
  /* background-color: greenyellow; */
  /* opacity also affects the socials container as well as profile-banner  */
  /* opacity: .75; */
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 10in;
  /* relative makes the socials-container go behind the profile container */
  position: relative;
}

.profile-banner {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* take 50% height of relative parent */
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 2px solid greenyellow;
  background-color: black;
}

.profile-name {
  border: 2px solid grey;
}

.profile-msg {
  border: 2px solid grey;
  color: white;
}


/* socials */

.socials-container {
  position: fixed;
  size: 1in 1in 1in 1in;
  border: 1px solid violet;
  right: 0;
}

.socials-container>ul {
  border: solid 2px brown;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.socials-container>ul>li {
  border: solid 2px goldenrod;
}

.socials-container svg {
  opacity: .25;
}


/* about section */

section#about {
  background-color: rgb(65, 65, 65);
  border: 2px solid rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav>
  <ul>
    <div class="logo-container">
      <a href="./index.html">
        <svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 512 512" fill="white"><path d="..."/></svg>
      </a>
    </div>
    <li>
      <a href="#about">
        <svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 32 32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="white">
<path d="..."  style="-inkscape-stroke:none" fill-rule="evenodd" /></svg>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#projects">
        <svg height="40" width="40" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 380.807 380.807" fill="white"><path d="..." /></svg>
      </a>
    </li>
    <div class="contact-container">
      <a href="#contact">
        <svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path 
d="..." stroke="white"  stroke-width="1.5"  stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" /></svg>
      </a>
    </div>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="socials-container">
  <ul>
    <li class="github-item">
      <a href="https://github.com/08Miguel24">
        <svg width="35" height="35" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path 
fill="none"  d="M0 0h24v24H0z" />
<path d="M12 2a10 10 0 00-3.16 19.5c.5.08.66-.23.66-.5v-1.69C6.73 19.91 6.14 18 6.14 18A2.69 2.69 0 005 16.5c-.91-.62.07-.6.07-.6a2.1 2.1 0 011.53 1 2.15 2.15 0 002.91.83 2.16 2.16 0 01.63-1.34C8 16.17 5.62 15.31 5.62 11.5a3.87 3.87 0 011-2.71 3.58 3.58 0 01.1-2.64s.84-.27 2.75 1a9.63 9.63 0 015 0c1.91-1.29 2.75-1 2.75-1a3.58 3.58 0 01.1 2.64 3.87 3.87 0 011 2.71c0 3.82-2.34 4.66-4.57 4.91a2.39 2.39 0 01.69 1.85V21c0 .27.16.59.67.5A10 10 0 0012 2z" /></svg>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="linkedin-item">
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/michaelcueva/">
        <svg width="35" height="35" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> <path
 d="M18.72 4H5.37A1.31 1.31 0 004 5.25v13.38A1.41 1.41 0 005.37 20h13.35A1.34 1.34 0 0020 18.63V5.25A1.23 1.23 0 0018.72 4zM9 17.34H6.67v-7.13H9v7.13zM7.89 9.13A1.18 1.18 0 016.67 7.9a1.18 1.18 0 011.24-1.23A1.18 1.18 0 019.13 7.9a1.18 1.18 0 01-1.24 1.23zm9.45 8.21H15v-3.9c0-.93-.33-1.57-1.16-1.57a1.25 1.25 0 00-1.17.84 1.431 1.431 0 00-.08.57v4.06h-2.3v-7.13h2.3v1a2.32 2.32 0 012.1-1.21c1.51 0 2.65 1 2.65 3.13v4.21z" /></svg>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="kaggle-item">
      <a href="https://www.kaggle.com/michaelcueva">
        <svg width="35" height="35" viewBox="0 0 32 32" fill="white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path  d="M25.099 31.812c-.025.12-.156.188-.375.188h-4.183c-.249 0-.468-.109-.656-.328l-6.907-8.787-1.932 1.828v6.817c0 .313-.151.469-.463.469H7.338c-.312 0-.469-.156-.469-.469V.469c0-.308.157-.469.469-.469h3.245c.312 0 .463.161.463.469v19.124l8.271-8.359c.224-.224.443-.328.661-.328h4.319c.192 0 .317.077.38.239.063.199.047.339-.047.417l-8.74 8.459 9.115 11.343c.125.141.156.276.093.48z" /></svg>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<section id="landing">
  <div class="profile-container">
    <div class="profile-banner">
      <p class="profile-name">Name</p>
      <p class="profile-msg">Pleased to meet you, my name is Michael, I am a writer</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="about">
  <div>
    About
  </div>

  <h4>Other work </h4>
  <p>I do clinical work specializing in behavioral psychology</p>
</section>
```

For some reason when I'm scrolled in the `section#landing` element I can't seem to click the `socials-container` but when I scroll to the `section#about` element I can seemingly click the `socials-container`.

I've tested this by setting the `background-color` of `profiles-container` and I can confirm that the `socials-container` disappears behind the `section#landing`. What might be the reason for this?

Comment: you need to adjust the z-index

Answer (score 0):

Just like @Temani Afif said, adding this `z-index` in your css make you control the position of your div(ei. front or back)

The content of your `socials-container` class may look like this.

```
.socials-container {
  z-index: 1; /* Add this. */
  position: fixed;
  size: 1in 1in 1in 1in;
  border: 1px solid violet;
  right: 0;
}
```

I just add this snippet just in case.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cormorant&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cinzel&family=Cormorant&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cinzel&family=Cormorant&family=Montserrat&display=swap');
:root {
  --primary-font: 'Cinzel', serif;
  --secondary-font: 'Cormorant', serif;
  --tertiary-font: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  --primary-image: url('./images/masteroogway.jpg');
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  background-image: var(--primary-image);
  font-family: var(--primary-font);
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}


/* navbar */

nav {
  /* background-color: black;
    opacity: .75; */
  border: solid 2px;
  border-color: blueviolet;
}

nav>ul {
  border: solid 2px brown;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

nav>ul>div.logo-container {
  border: solid 2px goldenrod;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

nav>ul>li {
  border: solid 2px greenyellow;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

nav>ul>li>a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav>ul>li>a:hover {
  color: grey;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px white;
}

nav>ul>div.contact-container {
  border: solid 2px goldenrod;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}


/* landing */

section#landing {
  border: 2px solid rgb(58, 209, 255);
}

.profile-container {
  /* background-color: greenyellow; */
  /* opacity also affects the socials container as well as profile-banner  */
  /* opacity: .75; */
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 10in;
  /* relative makes the socials-container go behind the profile container */
  position: relative;
}

.profile-banner {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* take 50% height of relative parent */
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 2px solid greenyellow;
  background-color: black;
}

.profile-name {
  border: 2px solid grey;
}

.profile-msg {
  border: 2px solid grey;
  color: white;
}


/* socials */

.socials-container {
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: gray;
  position: fixed;
  size: 1in 1in 1in 1in;
  border: 1px solid violet;
  right: 0;
}

.socials-container>ul {
  border: solid 2px brown;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.socials-container>ul>li {
  border: solid 2px goldenrod;
}

.socials-container svg {
  opacity: .25;
}


/* about section */

section#about {
  background-color: rgb(65, 65, 65);
  border: 2px solid rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav>
  <ul>
    <div class="logo-container">
      <a href="./index.html">
        <svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 512 512" fill="white"><path d="..."/></svg>
      </a>
    </div>
    <li>
      <a href="#about">
        <svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 32 32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="white">
<path d="..."  style="-inkscape-stroke:none" fill-rule="evenodd" /></svg>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#projects">
        <svg height="40" width="40" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 380.807 380.807" fill="white"><path d="..." /></svg>
      </a>
    </li>
    <div class="contact-container">
      <a href="#contact">
        <svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path 
d="..." stroke="white"  stroke-width="1.5"  stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" /></svg>
      </a>
    </div>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="socials-container">
  <ul>
    <li class="github-item">
      <a href="https://github.com/08Miguel24">
        <svg width="35" height="35" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path 
fill="none"  d="M0 0h24v24H0z" />
<path d="M12 2a10 10 0 00-3.16 19.5c.5.08.66-.23.66-.5v-1.69C6.73 19.91 6.14 18 6.14 18A2.69 2.69 0 005 16.5c-.91-.62.07-.6.07-.6a2.1 2.1 0 011.53 1 2.15 2.15 0 002.91.83 2.16 2.16 0 01.63-1.34C8 16.17 5.62 15.31 5.62 11.5a3.87 3.87 0 011-2.71 3.58 3.58 0 01.1-2.64s.84-.27 2.75 1a9.63 9.63 0 015 0c1.91-1.29 2.75-1 2.75-1a3.58 3.58 0 01.1 2.64 3.87 3.87 0 011 2.71c0 3.82-2.34 4.66-4.57 4.91a2.39 2.39 0 01.69 1.85V21c0 .27.16.59.67.5A10 10 0 0012 2z" /></svg>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="linkedin-item">
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/michaelcueva/">
        <svg width="35" height="35" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> <path
 d="M18.72 4H5.37A1.31 1.31 0 004 5.25v13.38A1.41 1.41 0 005.37 20h13.35A1.34 1.34 0 0020 18.63V5.25A1.23 1.23 0 0018.72 4zM9 17.34H6.67v-7.13H9v7.13zM7.89 9.13A1.18 1.18 0 016.67 7.9a1.18 1.18 0 011.24-1.23A1.18 1.18 0 019.13 7.9a1.18 1.18 0 01-1.24 1.23zm9.45 8.21H15v-3.9c0-.93-.33-1.57-1.16-1.57a1.25 1.25 0 00-1.17.84 1.431 1.431 0 00-.08.57v4.06h-2.3v-7.13h2.3v1a2.32 2.32 0 012.1-1.21c1.51 0 2.65 1 2.65 3.13v4.21z" /></svg>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="kaggle-item">
      <a href="https://www.kaggle.com/michaelcueva">
        <svg width="35" height="35" viewBox="0 0 32 32" fill="white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path  d="M25.099 31.812c-.025.12-.156.188-.375.188h-4.183c-.249 0-.468-.109-.656-.328l-6.907-8.787-1.932 1.828v6.817c0 .313-.151.469-.463.469H7.338c-.312 0-.469-.156-.469-.469V.469c0-.308.157-.469.469-.469h3.245c.312 0 .463.161.463.469v19.124l8.271-8.359c.224-.224.443-.328.661-.328h4.319c.192 0 .317.077.38.239.063.199.047.339-.047.417l-8.74 8.459 9.115 11.343c.125.141.156.276.093.48z" /></svg>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<section id="landing">
  <div class="profile-container">
    <div class="profile-banner">
      <p class="profile-name">Name</p>
      <p class="profile-msg">Pleased to meet you, my name is Michael, I am a writer</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="about">
  <div>
    About
  </div>

  <h4>Other work </h4>
  <p>I do clinical work specializing in behavioral psychology</p>
</section>
```